# Targetting and Changing HTML content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the "10" in the HTML below using jQuery:

```
<div id="ingredients">
<h2>Ingredients</h2>
<h4>Sugar: <span class="sugar">10</span></h4>
```

Here have been the iterations that I've gone through that have been unsuccessful:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ingredients.sugar').html("5");
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span[class=sugar]').html("5");
});
```

In addition, how would I store the value of "10" in a variable? I'm trying to do this:

```
var $sugar = $('#ingredients.sugar').html();
```

Would that work?

Thanks!

Henry

Comment: *"Would that work?"* - Well what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed space in your selector, this will work:

```
$('#ingredients .sugar').html("5");
```

Comment: o m g... i didn't even realize that was part of the syntax. THANKS!

Comment: You didn't offer a solution for storing the original value.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ingredients .sugar').html("5");
});
```

Notice the space between; this says look for a .sugar child from the #ingredients parent.  You should also be able to do:

```
var val = $('#ingredients .sugar').html();
```

Comment: didn't even notice the space was part of the syntax. thanks for answering my variable question as well!

Comment: Your example for caching the original version is wrong. It should use `.html()` not `.html("5")`.

Comment: @Valjas Your comment is wrong. Check return value of html() function in jQ.

Comment: @c-smile, it isn't wrong. With the way provided above value is updated in the page, but the `val` is an object instead of the value `10`.

Comment: My getter (second statement should be `html()` to return the value correctly, yes.  Thanks for the catch.  Where was caching mentioned as part of this?  Looked like a simple assignment question.

Comment: @BrianMains I was referring to caching in the JavaScript sense. Caching the value within a JavaScript var to avoid having to read from the DOM again. It could simply be referred to as storing or grabbing the value as well. ;) Thanks for fixing, upvoted you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with a simplified selector (don't need `#ingredients`), factory caching and update without using quotes (`5` works fine).

```
// Document ready
$(function () {
    var $sugar = $( '.sugar' ), // Cache jQuery factory
        originalValue = $sugar.html(); // Cache original value
    // Update value
    $sugar.html( 5 );
});
```